# How remove focus javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, wai-aria

I need to remove focus on element and after goes to another when the user click tab.

Suppose to hae 2 elements, one input and one button. when the use goes in this page the input is must be focused and when the user click on tab needs to focus the button:

To select the first element I do:

```
this.someInput.nativeElement.focus();
```

and when the user clicks tab I do:

```
@ViewChild('someInput', { read: ElementRef }) someInput: ElementRef;

  this.renderer.listen('document', 'keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 9) {
        this.someInput.nativeElement.blur();
        event.preventDefault();

      }
    });
```

under the input and button there are others components that I want to select with tab but for now it is not important.The problem is that at the first the input is focused but whe I click tab the focus doesn't move to button but It remains on input. Anyone can help me?

Comment: if you remove `event.preventDefault();` it should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ViewChild('someInput', { read: ElementRef }) someInput: ElementRef;
  // user someinput if you want to only affect the blur on one element
  this.someInput.nativeElement.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode === 9) {
        this.someInput.nativeElement.style.filer = 'blur(5)';
        debugger;  //is element blurred now?  
        event.preventDefault();

      }
    });
```

When you hit the breakpoint, open the console and type in this.someInput.nativeElement press enter.  You will be able to experiment with the style filter.